# Sort list for negatives are in the middle

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

I have a list of objects

```
public class foo
{
    public decimal val1 {get;set;}
    public decimal val2 {get;set;}
}
```

I `val1` and `val2` can contain both negative or positive values. 
if I have a `List<foo>items`   is there a clean way I can sort them so that a negative value in either val1 or val2 are not the first or last item in the list.

My list size can very from 1 - 100.  if it is less then 3 I do not need to sort. But if it is `>= 3` I need to make sure any negative values are not first or last in the list.

Comment: Is that possible? They might all be negative.

Comment: I'm curious too, can you elaborate more with a more descriptive example?

Comment: If they are all positive or all negative then the order is not important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would try to push a "positive" value to the head and the tail of the list if they exist:

```
if (myList.Count > 2)
{
    //push a positive to the head of the list
    var firstPositive = myList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.val1 > 0 && x.val2 > 0);
    if (firstPositive != null)
    {
        myList.Remove(firstPositive);
        myList.Insert(0, firstPositive);
    }

    //push a positive to the tail of the list
    var secondPositive = myList.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault(x => x.val1 > 0 && x.val2 > 0);
    if (secondPositive != null)
    {
        myList.Remove(secondPositive);
        myList.Add(secondPositive);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks much more readable then the solution I was thinking =)

Answer (score 1):

Create your own `MyList:List<decimal>` class and override `Add(..)`, `Insert(...)`, `Remove(..)` and other methods to fit your needs.

Or you can use [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) of `decimal` and listen for `CollectionChanged` event.